# How to bind all the data inside a div as a subset in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Here I am trying to save all the data entered in a form into database.

Currently, my HTML partial form is as below:

```
<% LookupValue.laststatus.each do |d| %>
  <div class="row row-margin" id="Counter">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= f.label :"#{d.LookupValueName}:", :class => "col-form-label float-md-right", :for=>"Metric:"+d.LookupValueName%>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= f.text_field :"Counter", :class => "form-control tala-count",:id =>"Counter"+d.LookupValueId.to_s, placeholder: "tala Count" %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= f.text_field :"Gantalu", :class => "form-control Gantalu",:id =>"Gantalu"+d.LookupValueId.to_s, placeholder: "Gantalu" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<%end%>

<div class="row row-margin other-metric-row">
  <% if last_LookupValue = LookupValue.status.last %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= f.text_field :"Gantalu", :class => "form-control other-metric",:id =>last_LookupValue.LookupValueId, placeholder: "Other" %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= f.text_field :"Counter", :class => "form-control tala-count",:id =>"Counter"+last_LookupValue.LookupValueId.to_s, placeholder: "tala Count" %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= f.text_field :"Gantalu", :class => "form-control Gantalu",:id =>"Counter"+last_LookupValue.LookupValueId.to_s, placeholder: "Gantalu" %>
    </div>
  <%end%>
</div>
```

and my UI is as follows:
[UI for the partial form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6Szs.png)

WHen I am passing the parameter as "Counter": `params.require(:final).permit(:Counter)` I see the data through console as below:

```
final[Counter]: Value1
final[Gantalu]: 1
final[Counter]: Value2
final[Gantalu]: 11
final[Counter]: Value3
final[Gantalu]: 111
final[Counter]: Value4
final[Gantalu]: 1111
final[Gantalu]: 
final[Counter]: 
final[Gantalu]:
```

Not sure how to get all the counter data under a single variable so that I can access all the data entered in every text box and access them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you imagine to get multiple fields in a single variable? Do you expect it to be an array?

Comment: Quoting as a variable might be wrong. But, my intention is to wrap all the entered text in the corresponding fields as an object of "Counter". Every text-box is having unique ID.

Comment: I am expecting the data as below for counter node with many sub values:


{
  'person' => {
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'Counter' => {
  'id' => 'Home',
        'tala' => 'Home',
        'gantalu' => '221b Baker Street'
      },
      {
  'id' => 'Home',
        'tala' => 'Home',
        'gantalu' => '221b Baker Street'
      }
`  }
}

Comment: BTW, you might want to check out the [Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide): Your naming is a bit *unconventional*.

Comment: Will do @jvillian. Meanwhile, can you help me with the solution per my query.

Comment: As I was not able to bind the data, I have created all the columns and passed to the required parameters. Then I was able to access the data without issues for every column